# class not getting applied in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am looking through a array in angular. For each element in the array there is a width attribute which dictates what the width of this element should be on screen. However, this does not get renedred for some reason.

The array is as below:

```
$scope.header = [
                    {'column':'name', 'width':'300'},
                    {'column':'city', 'width':'300'},
                    {'column':'address', 'width':'300'},
                    {'column':'age', 'width':'300'}
                    ];
```

The view is as below

```
<div ng-repeat="element in header" > 
  <span ng-bind="element.column"  style="display:inline-block;width:{{element.width}}" >
  </span>
</div>
```

Please advice

Comment: try adding px:

{{element.width}}px

Comment: do you have a fiddle o I can test it out?

Comment: Interesting that you ask about classes yet have inline styles, which are generally considered poor practice. Something similar could be done with ng-class and would adhere to best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle)

```
ng-style="{width: element.width + 'px'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[C. S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2277966/c-s) is right about needing `{{element.width}}px`.  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate. http://jsfiddle.net/nordyke/T7cW7/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add px after your {{expression}}, here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6hPU/)

```
<span ng-bind="element.column"  style="display:inline-block;width:{{element.width}}px" >
```

or even this:

```
<span ng-bind="element.column"  style="display:inline-block;width:{{element.width+'px'}}" >
```